# How to call a node.js script inside html?

Tags: node.js

Please excuse my ignorance.

I'm able to send an email with the following command from my apps directory via the command prompt.

`node send-email.js`

Though I'm having trouble executing the script from inside my html page, for example via a button click.

What are my steps to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: node is a system command. Your browser for security reasons has no access to your system. Maybe you should place this send-email.js on a web site, and call it via an API call when button click.

Answer (score 2):

1. NodeJS runs on **server-side**, HTML files are running on **client's Web Browser**.
2. Because of that, you **can't run** a Javascript code which exists in the server-side at the client-side just **because they are both Javascript**.
3. If you want to send an email by clicking a button in a web page, you can send a POST request to the NodeJS (or PHP, or Asp.NET...) server to make it send an email.

There are some nice webserver frameworks for NodeJS called [express.js](https://expressjs.com/), [koa.js](https://koajs.com/) and etc. You can use them to receive http requests from clients and process them. (like adding an item to a database, making an user logged in, and all kinds of server stuff...)